# Is it a good practice to use a single fragment to display the UI instead of the activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns, android-activity, architecture

As the title states, does it considered as a good practice to use a single fragment within an activity to display the content? I began to notice that more and more developers start to use the fragment as an insulation layer to separate the lifecycle logic from UI that activity (sorry, fragment) displays. The most recent example that I stumble on is the [`architecture blueprints`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) provided by Google developers. They [`use`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksActivity.java) just one single fragment for UI while the activity handles ViewModel and all the navigation between screens.

So, is this a good practice or just a personal preference? Would you care to share your opinion on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

Using Fragments as your UI is a good practice.

1. Activity can hold all common logic, while you can use different fragments to show different UI for mobile vs tablet.
2. If the UI is in Fragment, you can reuse it in multiple activities.
3. If you have a workflow scenario like Registration flow, using a single activity with multiple fragments will help you out a lot.
4. Manipulation of fragment backstack is a lot easier than trying to do the same with activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment for display the UI is good,Reason is listed below:-
1.You can create one activity,and display multiple fragment inside that activity.
2.Handling back press is easy as you can override onBackpress() in main activity class  and handle back key event from fragment(s) as check its(fragment) visibility and handle event.
3. Reusability of layout.
4. Reusability of fragment.
5. Handling different action menu is very easy for different fragment(s).